# What are other ways to refer to a "Window Run Channel" ?

Tags: window

Sorry for the newbie question:

I'm looking to replace the front driver-side window run channels in my 2003 Corolla. I figure I might as well do the other three while I'm at it—but, wherever I look, I see something like [this](https://parts.toyotaofcoolsprings.com/oem-parts/toyota-run-channel-6815102210); that is, $70 for a piece of rubber for *one* window.

Now, I only know of this part by "window run channel," and am not sure what else it's called. I am confident that if I had other ways of referring to it, I could find a much cheaper price. What else might one call this part?

It is, basically, the rubber that fits around the window frame into which the window fits when it's rolled up:

[image: schematic picture of a run channel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other words I used to perform a search are "window guide channel" and "window weatherstrip channel."  Each of these searches returned different results in wording, but nearly identical products. The prices appeared to range from about US$40 to nearly double that figure. Some of the returns also indicated one can purchase used guide channel from eBay and also some online salvage services.